# Change all R columns names using a reference file

Tags: r, dataframe, rename, cbind

I am trying to rename columns in a dataframe in `R`. However, the renaming has circular referencing. I would like a solution to this problem, the circular referencing cannot be avoided. One way to think was to rename a column and move it to a new `dataframe`, hence, avoiding the circular referencing. However, I am unable to do so.

The renaming reference is as follows:

[image]

The current function I am using is as follows:

```
standard_mapping <- function(mapping.col, current_name, standard_name, data){
  for(i in 1:nrow(mapping.col)) {
    # i =32
    print(i)
    eval(parse(text = paste0("std.name = mapping.col[",i,",'",new_name,"']")))
    eval(parse(text = paste0("data.name = mapping.col[",i,",'",old_name,"']")))

    if(data.name %in% colnames(data)){
      setnames(data, old=c(data.name), new = c(std.name))
    }
  }
  return(data)
}
```

Mapping.col is referred to the image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rename multiple colums at the same time, and there's no need to move the data itself that's stored in your data.frame. If you know the right order, you can just use

```
names(data) <- mapping.col$new_name
```

If the order is different, you can use `match` to first match them to the right positions:

```
names(data) <- mapping.col$new_name[match(names(data), mapping.col$old_name)]
```

By the way, assigning names and other attributes is always done by some sort of assignment. The `setNames` returns something, that still needs assigning.

Comment: Makes my dataset completely blank, tried using the match piece of code. Looking further into it