# Change name of few columns of dataframe using another dataframe. To keep it dynamic, need to match using the name of columns, instead of position

Tags: r, match, multiple-columns

I looked up a lot of similar questions on Stackoverflow but I could not locate the one I am asking.

Consider a dataset:

`A B C D E F G
a b c d e f g`

And mapping dataset to be:
current desired

`B        H
C        I
D        J
E        K
F        L`

`namechangevector <- c('B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F')`

I am using this command:

`colnames(data[namechangevector]) <- as.character(mappingdata$desired[match(names(data[namechangevectors]), mappingdata$current)])`

But, this doesn't work. However, this works:

`colnames(data)[2:6] <- as.character(mappingdata$desired[match(names(data[namechangevectors]), mappingdata$current)])`

But since, the vector can have more values and dataset can keep changing. I want to match using the vector and not the position. Please help!

Comment: What about: `colnames(data)[which(colnames(data) %in% namechangevector)] <- ...`? Also, it is always good to include a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with your question.

Comment: Did not work. The command makes no change to the data

Comment: Ok, can you provide a reproducible example with your expected results?

Comment: `names(data)[names(data) %in% namechangevector] <-new.namechangevector`. Also in your first command, try changing `colnames(data)[namechangevector] <-` instead of `colnames(data[namechangevector]) <-` , it's a very subtle difference, look at your second code for a clue

Comment: I did try colnames(data)[namechangevector], but this doesn't work either. Neither does this:   `colnames(data)[which(colnames(data) %in% namechangevector)] <- as.character(mappingdata$desired[match(names(data[namechangevector]), mappingdata$current)])`

Comment: I am working on dummy reproducible data

Comment: Refer to this for an example. Just a few columns instead of all/. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53714977/change-all-r-columns-names-using-a-reference-file

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53714977/change-all-r-columns-names-using-a-reference-file